# How to synthesis the verilog code using memories inside combinational logic .?

Tags: verilog

I use the buffers inside Verilog code combinational logic, I'm trying to synthesis the Verilog code using the spyglass synthesis tool. but I'm not able to do it.
Showing

> Error : latch inferred for signal buffer A, buffer B.

I attach my Verilog code below, can anyone help me how to solve the problem.

Thank you

Here is my code :

```
    module FIFObuffer (Clk,Reset,Enable, dataIn,dataOut); 
    input Clk,Reset,Enable;
    input signed[16:0]dataIn;
    output reg [16:0]dataOut; 
    //internal registers 
     reg signed [16:0]data_1;




                           
        reg [16:0] A[0:107];                      // 
        Circular buffers A & B
        reg [16:0] B[0:107];
        reg [16:0]Counter    = 0;
        reg [16:0]writecount = 0;
        reg [16:0]readcount  = 1; 

         reg signed [16:0]C_A;
         reg signed [16:0]C_B;


     always@(*)begin 
    
    
    if (Enable)begin 

        A[writecount] = dataIn;                  
        //Circular buffer 
        B[writecount] = Counter+1;
        C_A = A[writecount];
        C_B = B[writecount];
        writecount = writecount+1;
        Counter=0;
    end
    else begin
        A[writecount] = dataIn;                  
        //Circular buffer 
        B[writecount] = Counter+1;
        C_A = A[writecount];
        C_B = B[writecount];
        writecount = writecount+1;
        Counter=0;
    end 
        
end module
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're getting inferred latches is because you're not using your provided clock. Clocked memory becomes registers or RAMs, unclocked memory is a latch. Your `always` block is currently combinational because it's an `always@(*)` which means "run this code any time any of the inputs changes." Instead, you want a clocked block: `always@(posedge Clk)` which runs any time there's a positive edge on `Clk`. Memory that changes on a clock edge is a register or RAM.

Example:

```
always@(posedge Clk) begin
    if (Reset) begin //positive, synchronous reset
        //reset your counters to zero
        Counter <= 0;
        ReadCounter <= 0;
        WriteCounter <= 0;
    end else begin //your functional code starts here, I just copied yours in with minor changes
        if (Enable)begin
            A[WriteCounter] <= dataIn; //note the use of delayed (<=) assignments - these are necessary when creating clocked logic
            //etc. etc.
        end
    end
end
```